# How Do I Generate a List of Items Not Shared Between Two Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

Basically, I have a single list of a bunch of unique items that are categorized by color (Items). I do some stuff and generate a dataframe with selected combinations of these unique items (Combinations).  My goal is to make a list of the items from the original list that do not appear in the Combinations dataframe. Ideally, I'd like to check all four color columns, but for my initial test, I just selected the "Red" column.

```
import pandas as pd

Items = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ["6917529336306454104","6917529268375577150","6917529175831101427","6917529351156928903","6917529249201580539","6917529246740186376","6917529286870790429","6917529212665335174","6917529206310658443","6917529207434353786","6917529309798817021","6917529352287607192","6917529268327711171","6917529316674574229"
],'Type': ['Red','Blue','Green','Cyan','Red','Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue','Green','Green','Green','Cyan','Cyan']})

Items = Items.set_index('Id', drop=True)

#Do stuff

Combinations = pd.DataFrame({
    'Red':  ["6917529336306454104","6917529336306454104","6917529336306454104","6917529336306454104"],
    'Blue': ["6917529268375577150","6917529286870790429","6917529206310658443","6917529206310658443"],
    'Green': ["6917529175831101427","6917529207434353786","6917529309798817021","6917529309798817021"],
    'Cyan': ["6917529351156928903","6917529268327711171","6917529351156928903","6917529268327711171"],
    'Other': [12,15,18,32]
})
```

My first attempt was using the line below, but this raises the execution error "KeyError: 'Id'". A forum post indicated that the `drop=True` in the `set_index` might resolve it, but that didn't seem to work in my case.

```
UnusedItems = ~Items[Items['Id'].isin(list(Combinations['Red']))]
```

I attempted to work around it by using this line. While it executes, it generates an empty dataframe. Just by inspection, item 6917529249201580539 should be returned when considering the "Red" column. Considering all Combination columns, items 6917529249201580539, 6917529246740186376, 6917529212665335174, and 6917529316674574229 should be returned as unused.

```
UnusedItems = ~Items[Items.iloc[:,0].isin(list(Combinations['Red']))]
```

I'd appreciate and ideas or guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.melt()` on Combination, then change both into sets and subtract

```
set(Items.index) - set(Combinations.melt().value)
```

Comment: I really like this approach. I did implement the column reduction (@Henry) prior to applying the ``.melt()``.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to grab the first 4 columns from `Combinations` with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc) and reformat to long form with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack):

```
(Combinations.iloc[:, :4].stack()
 .droplevel(0).rename_axis(index='Type').reset_index(name='Id'))
```

```
     Type                   Id
0     Red  6917529336306454104
1    Blue  6917529268375577150
2   Green  6917529175831101427
3    Cyan  6917529351156928903
4     Red  6917529336306454104
5    Blue  6917529286870790429
6   Green  6917529207434353786
7    Cyan  6917529268327711171
8     Red  6917529336306454104
9    Blue  6917529206310658443
10  Green  6917529309798817021
11   Cyan  6917529351156928903
12    Red  6917529336306454104
13   Blue  6917529206310658443
14  Green  6917529309798817021
15   Cyan  6917529268327711171
```

Then perform an Anti-Join with `Items`, [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) to get the 'Id' column back from the index, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) with indicator, and [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) to filter out values that are present in both frames, then [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) the indicator column:

```
UnusedItems = Items.reset_index().merge(
    Combinations.iloc[:, :4].stack()
        .droplevel(0).rename_axis(index='Type').reset_index(name='Id'),
    how='outer',
    indicator='I').query('I != "both"').drop('I', 1)
```

`UnusedItems`:

```
                     Id   Type
8   6917529249201580539    Red
9   6917529246740186376   Blue
11  6917529212665335174   Blue
17  6917529352287607192  Green
20  6917529316674574229   Cyan
```

Comment: my full Combinations dataframe has 19 columns. Can the ``.drop`` function be modified to drop from 'Other' all the way to the end just leaving the first four color columns? Although, it might be easier to just copy the four color columns and then proceed with the ``.stack``.

Comment: Yes. I would go with `Combinations.iloc[:, :4].stack(......` to grab the first 4 columns by index location then stack, or explicitly grab the columns `Combinations[['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Cyan']].stack(....`